# Intervals for polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am unsure of the value you use as the maximum endpoint for the $\theta$ interval (usually for a circle), e.g. when do I use $\pi$, $2\pi$ or $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

I thought it was when you use half a circle you use $2\pi$ and quarter you use $\pi$, but my teacher used $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ for the quarter. Is there a more specific rule?

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is right.

For a complete circle you need $2\pi$,

so for a half of a circle you need one half of $2\pi$, surely  $\pi$

and hope it's clear now, for a quarter of a circle you need a quarter of
$2\pi$, which equals $\frac{\pi }{2}$.

Comment: @Mi-Lee Your wellcome. More or less it's nothing else, but calculating with fractions.